# Fast bit reversal with mirrored arithmetics

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, fft

I include a C function from an article on FFT by Sergey Chernenko. This function rearranges data by performing an even-odd decomposition. But instead of using bit reversal it does so by adding 1 in a mirrored manner, which is much faster than other reversing code I have tested.

```
  /*
      http://www.librow.com/articles/article-10 (Sergey Chernenko)
   */
  void rearrange(float* Data, const unsigned int N) {

     //   Swap position
     unsigned int Target = 0;
     //   Process all positions of input signal
     for (unsigned int Position = 0; Position < N; ++Position)
     {
        //   Only for not yet swapped entries
        if (Target > Position)
        {
           //   Swap entries
           const float Temp = Data[Target];
           Data[Target] = Data[Position];
           Data[Position] = Temp;
        }
        //   Bit mask
        unsigned int Mask = N;
        //   While bit is set
        while (Target & (Mask >>= 1))
           //   Drop bit
           Target &= ~Mask;
        //   The current bit is 0 - set it
        Target |= Mask;
     }
  }
```

The part that interests me is the the mirrored incrementing code. I understand bit-wise operations in C and I can mentally go through this snippet and validate that it works. What I don't yet understand is why it works. How do I come up with this solution?

```
        //   Bit mask
        unsigned int Mask = N;
        //   While bit is set
        while (Target & (Mask >>= 1))
           //   Drop bit
           Target &= ~Mask;
        //   The current bit is 0 - set it
        Target |= Mask;
```

Comment: As a side note, you can see some really nice "Bit Twiddling Hacks" here: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Some of them may actually come in handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand why this works, first think of how a normal increment functions: given an arbitrary bit pattern, an increment finds a run (which may be empty) of consecutive ones until a zero, clears out all ones, and sets the first zero to one, like this:

```
0000 0001 -  0 ->  1 | No ones at the back (an empty run): insert 1 right away.
0111 1000 -  7 ->  8 | Replace a run of three ones with zeros, then insert 1
1011 1100 - 11 -> 12 | Replace a run of two ones with zeros, then insert 1
```

Now consider your algorithm: the regular increment detects runs starting at the back of the number; your loop detects runs starting at the front of the number. Since you say the algorithm "adds one in a mirrored manner", `N` must be the twice the highest power of two that may be present in the `Target`. The `while` loop tries to find a position in the `Target` where the position of the lone `1` in the `Mask` matches a zero - the first "hole". The body of the loop clears out all ones in the target, starting with the highest-order one. As soon as the loop stops, the `Target |= Mask` inserts `1` into the "hole" found by the loop.

Comment: Wow, thanks. You really nailed it. Had to do some scribbling on a piece of paper, but I finally get it, sweet. The while function exits if a 1 can be inserted. If not, it's inserting 0s while there are 1s and inserts a new 1 in the end.

Comment: @Davorin Correct -- the *post-condition* of a `while` loop is the inverse of its *continuation* condition. Since the continuation condition of your `while` loop is `(Target & Mask) != 0` (I wrote the condition with an explicit comparison to zero and no side effects), the post-condition is `(Target & Mask) == 0`, which simply means that the `1` can be inserted at the `Mask`.

Answer (score 1):

It's just emulating addition with 1, position by position. Except with the positions reversed.

To add 1, you keep modifying bit positions (starting with least-significant) until there is no longer a carry.